# BOTO3 S3 file copy blocking or non blocking?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is BOTO3 S3 file [copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) blocking or non blocking? Also can I add extra metadata to destination object during copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's blocking. I learned this not from the documentation, but by looking at the [source code for TransferManager](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html), which is what does the work.

If you want to provide new metadata for the destination, then use the `ExtraArgs` parameter. Be aware that the supported arguments are limited, and have different names than you might expect (eg, `ContentType` rather than `Content-Type`).

However, I don't recommend that you use `copy()`, because it works by downloading the file to your client and then uploading. This introduces delays, the possibility of errors, and potentially increased costs for data transfer.

Instead, if you're copying files on S3, use [copy_object()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object). You'll still pay data transfer charges, but the copy will execute entirely within S3, so is much faster.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But as I know copy_object() has limitation of 5GB file size, otherwise you have to configure multipart. Do you have any experience on this?

Comment: @MinuddinAhmedRana - I've done multi-part uploads, but not multi-part copy. But it looks straightforward: the only difference is that you call `upload_part_copy()` rather than `upload_part()`. I think it makes sense to use the largest possible part size when copying, unlike uploads (where the ability to retry and get feedback is often more important over a lower-bandwidth connection).